# Restful WebAPI VS Regular Controllers

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing some R&D on what seems like a very confusing topic, I've also read quite a few of the other SO questions, but I feel my question might be unique enough to warrant me asking. We've never developed an app using pure WebAPI.

**We're trying to write a SPA style app, where the back end is fully decoupled from the front end code**

Assuming our service does not know anything about who is accessing/consuming it:

WebAPI seems like the logical route to serve data, as opposed to using the standard MVC controllers, and serving our data via an action result and converting it to JSON. This to me at least seems like an MC design... which seems odd, and not what MVC was meant for.
(look mom... no view)

What would be considered normal convention in terms of performing action(y) calls?

*My sense is that my understanding of WebAPI is incorrect.*

The way I perceive WebAPI, is that its meant to be used in a CRUD sense, but what if I want to do something like: "InitialiseMonthEndPayment".... Would I need to create a WebAPI controller, called InitialiseMonthEndPaymentController, and then perform a POST... Seems a bit weird, as opposed to a MVC controller where i can just add a new action on the MonthEnd controller called InitialisePayment.

Or does this require a mindset shift in terms of design?

Any further links on this topic will be really useful, as my fear is we implement something that might be weird an could turn into a coding/maintenance concern later on?

Comment: Views move to Javascript modules. Take a look at the [Hot Towel SPA example](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) to get a feel for how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to make your services RESTful, the controller should represent a resource. In your example, the resource is `Payment`, so the controller would be called `PaymentController`.

You can have multiple POST methods in the same controller. In your scenario, I would call the action method `PostMonthlyPayment` or something similar. The URL (routing) would look like `http://server.com/api/payment/monthly` and the body (assuming JSON) would be something like:

```
{
   user: user@internet.com,
   month: 10,
   year: 2013,
   // any additional data
}
```

If the payment goes through, a good practice is to return HTTP error code 201 and the Location HTTP Header containing the URL to the payment GET method. If any data in the body is wrong, return a error code 400. If a payment had already been made by the user, conflict code 409 can work.

Comment: I like this suggestion. will try it out in a proof of concept. But seems a like the issue is definitely a shift of how we go about designing/programming currently.

Comment: Just out of interest if i update the rouer do allow me to supply another additional parameter eg "monthly", is there a way to do so specific to this controller? (eg, not all controllers now have access to an additional parameter for say, "Duration" (where duration is monthly))

Comment: You would need to use a custom route. Web Api 2.0/MVC 5 supports attribute based routing.

Answer (score 0):

For SPA you will definitely need REST Web Sevice. My suggestion is to try [servicestack](http://www.servicestack.net/) instead WebApi